# Need help decoding OSHA datasets numeric codes

Tags: labor

I need reference tables to decodify OSHA numberic codes for the multiple fields in the OSHA datasets. Many of these fields reference numeric codes for which I have not been able to find anywhere.

The list of data tables I am working with are located at: 
http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/#osha_accident_injury

Below is an example column from the accident_injury table:

COLUMN NAME = fat_cause

COLUMN DESCRIPTION = Construction - cause of fatality (code table CAUS)

Under this column are numeric codes that range from 1-30. I would like to know where I can access the code table CAUS referenced in the table dictionary as well as all the other codes.

Thanks.

Comment: I am checking in with my colleagues in OSHA and I hope to have a response for you soon.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Look forward to knowing what you are able to find out. I contact several OSHA offices and no one could tell me what the codes mean, but they suspect it is from an NCR system that is no longer used by OSHA.

Comment: I got what you're looking for.  We're working on getting it posted shortly.  First as an excel file and then shortly thereafter, we'll link to it on developer.dol.gov.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the information you need: http://www.dol.gov/open/xls/IMISCodes.xlsx

We will also be updating developer.dol.gov shortly.

If you have any more questions about it, please don't hesitate to ask.

EDIT 2018-01-29: [IMIS Codes live here now](http://developer.dol.gov/docs/IMISCodes.xlsx)

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is exactly what we've been searching for some time. I appreciate the quick response. Best, Michael.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do some googling around but I think what you're looking for is at http://www1.dol-esa.gov/AgcyData/agencyDataServlet

I found the same data at http://www.dol.gov/owcp/dfec/regs/compliance/dfecdd/CMFDataDictionary20091211.html as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark, 
This data dictionary references workers comp data. How can I be sure it applicable to OSHA data?